# moment.format() of date for next year in last week of current return with current year

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs

I have something strange here with using the dates and method [.format()](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) of the [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs) with Angular.js project, the issue simply that I get the correct day when I print it using [.toISOString()](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-iso-string/) but totally wrong with `.format()` the following example show the case :

Code like this :

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.isoString = moment().week(53).weekday(6).toISOString();
  $scope.formatString = moment().week(53).weekday(6).format('Do of MMMM GGGG');
  $scope.year = moment().week(53).weekday(6).years();
});
```

Return with result like this:

```
Correct ISO String : 2016-01-02T09:40:31.236Z 
Incorrect formate String: 2nd of January 2015 
Year : 2016
```

This is the showcase in [plnkr.co](http://plnkr.co/edit/sfLpF9W8lUThnMPkx65y?p=preview)

Any solution or description for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `YYYY` for the year instead of `GGGG`:

```
$scope.formatString = moment().week(53).weekday(6).format('Do of MMMM YYYY');
```

Comment: OMG how stupid am I. wot his works. my bad eyes with wrong docs, but for real what the `GGGG` ? what the point.